# How to list files owned by me for quota checking?

Tags: linux, quota

On Linux (RHEL 6) what is the best way to list all the files and sizes that are counting against my quota on a given filesystem?

We have a projects directory and everything I am currently doing is pretty small but my quota is nearly full and I want to see what else is mine so I can clean a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `find`, you should use a way that is safe regarding spaces and other funny symbols that can appear in filenames. This should do (provided your `find` and `du` versions accept the options):

```
find . -type f -user "$USER" -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

(the `-c` option is to have a nice total at the end). This will not count the size of the directories though.

If in the directory tree you have some directories that are not accessible by you, you might get some junk (permission denied) on your screen, so you might want to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` as:

```
find . -type f -user "$USER" -print0 2>/dev/null | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just do a find command based on username, I assume that is what they calculate the quota off.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -type f -user $(whoami)`; do
    du -h ${i}
done
```

That will list all files owned by $(whoami) with the file size in human readable format.

Though, that list is really long on my system, so I would probably suggest stdout to a file on that (`> output.txt`, for example) or adding `-maxdepth #` in the `find` command to limit it to a manageable level of directories.

Comment: I was thinking there was some way to do it like this with find.  Holy slow batman however.  But I bet one can't do much better.

Comment: @BrianLarsen I was trying to think of a way to find a faster one, because you're right this is relatively slow...  Also it requires a lot of manual labor to go through your list and clean out the files... If you don't care about the sizes it is way faster without the `du -h`.  Instead you could just run the `find . -type f -user NAME > output.txt` before leaving for the night and deal with it in the morning.  Or include a date in there, and AWK the older files that may not be so important.